# Does unsetting an array unset its elements in associated array?

Tags: php, arrays

This might be a silly question but just want to know and dont know how to search for it.

Code:

```
$_SESSION['My_Temp_Array'] = array(
                              'hello' => 'world', 
                              'foo' => array('bar' => 'bar')
                             );

if (isset($_SESSION['My_Temp_Array'])) {
   $hello = $_SESSION['My_Temp_Array']['hello'];
   $foo   = $_SESSION['My_Temp_Array']['foo'];

   //SEE #Q
   unset($_SESSION['My_Temp_Array']);
}
```

**#Q:**

`Does this also unset $_SESSION['My_Temp_Array']['hello'] AND $_SESSION['My_Temp_Array']['foo'] ? Or Do I need to unset them manually?`

I know I will not be able to access those inner keys once the array key is unset but do they stay in **memory**? Those arrays will hold large data, so in this example memory is not a problem but in my code it is.

**NOTE:** var_dump gives me null after its unset so I know they are not in array but are they saved in memory?

Comment: Do a `var_dump()` before and after to see for yourself

Comment: I did they can not be found its null, but im concerned with memory if its somehow saved in memory

Comment: They will stay in memory under PHP's garbage collector kicks in and cleans them up, or the script exits, which ever comes first.

Comment: @MarcB Is it possible to force garbage collector to run while script is running?

Comment: If you're on >=5.3, then there's [gc_collect_cycles()](http://php.net/gc_collect_cycles)

Answer (score 0):

They get unset and are eligible for reuse. If you want to be sure, you can first set the reference to 'null', before you do the unset.

```
$_SESSION['My_Temp_Array']['hello'] = null;
```

Note: If you are running PHP as CGI the memory will be freed after the request anyway, since the process is terminated.

Your mileage may very with apache module (will be freed at the latest when the apache child terminates) or FastCGI (depends on the configuration of how many requests are handled).